# Is $[(P \lor (Q \land R) ) \land (R’ \lor S) \land (S \to T’)] \to ( T \to P)$ valid using prepositional logic and inference in Discrete Mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Is the following argument valid? if not why?
$$((P \lor (Q \land R) ) \land (\lnot R \lor S) \land (S \to \lnot T)) \to ( T \to P)$$

Comment: The first clause has $P$ or $Q\wedge R$ true.  If $P$ is true, then $T\rightarrow P$ is true.  If $Q$ and $R$ are true, then $S$ is true, then $T$ is false, and so again $T\rightarrow P$ is true.  So whenever the LHS of the main implication is true, the RHS is true as well: the argument is valid.

Comment: Are people downvoting this because of "if not what is the interpretation where it does not hold?"  And, if so, can I change it to "And, if not, why?"

Comment: Such expressions can be checked by the [TreeProofGenerator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "interpretation" is the word you're looking for.  Maybe just say "And, if not, why?"

It is valid.

By conditional proof, assume the antecedent "[(P ∨ (Q ∧ R) ) ∧ (R’ ∨ S) ∧ (S → T’)]".

To prove the implication, you have to get from this assumption with rules of inference (and replacement) that "T → P".

"P' → T'" is equivalent to "T → P" by the rule of replacement named contrapositive.

So, you can instead infer the replacement "P' → T'".

So to prove "P' → T'", again by conditional proof, assume P'.

Now we prove T'.

From "[(P ∨ (Q ∧ R) ) ∧ (R’ ∨ S) ∧ (S → T’)]", we know "(P ∨ (Q ∧ R) )" and  "(R’ ∨ S)" and "(S → T’)]" are each true by conjunction elimination (twice).

So, from "(P ∨ (Q ∧ R) )", by assumption P', we know "Q ∧ R" must be true by disjunctive syllogism.

Then since R is true, we get from "(R’ ∨ S)" that S must be true by disjunctive syllogism.

Then since S is true, we get from "(S → T’)]" that T' must be true by modus ponens.

Then by conditional proof, "P' → T'".

Then by contrapositive "T → P".

Then by conditional proof "[(P ∨ (Q ∧ R) ) ∧ (R’ ∨ S) ∧ (S → T’)] → ( T → P)"

Comment: you mentioned, and I quote,
"P' → T'" is equivalent to "T → P" by the rule of replacement named contrapositive

However, doesn't that make implication operator "→" associative like as we know both ∧ and ∨ operators are associative?

And the contraposition rule is defined as:  P → Q derives Q′ → P′ . So are you making any mistake or something that you want to add?
Reference: Judith L. Gersting. 2006. Mathematical Structures for Computer Science. W. H. Freeman & Co., USA. Page-37. 7th Edition

Comment: @jarvis Rules of replacement are equivalences (or if you like, biconditional statements).  So, where you say "P implies Q derives not Q implies not P", yes that is true, but it goes the other direction as well: "not Q implies not P derives P implies Q"

Comment: @jarvis How would that make implication associative?

Comment: ok I did not notice the negation sign you used in the P and T. That "associative" part was mistakenly asked.

Comment: since we are on the topic, can you explain to me why bidirectionals (↔) are associative in nature?

Comment: @jarvis Can you please ask that in a new post and give me the link to it?  I'll answer it there. I need to get on my points game.

Comment: @jarvis Are you good on this one?  And, if so, can you please mark mine as the answer?

Comment: as a new user, I can not ask more questions now. So was looking for an ans in comment. But that's totally understandable. and yes marked your answer as it was a good one.

Comment: @jarvis Sorry, I got caught up in stuff.  I will ask it, answer it, and tag you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I put the expression $$((P \lor (Q \lor R) ) \land (\lnot R \lor S) \land (\lnot S \to T)) \to ( T \to P)$$
in the [Tree Proof Generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((P%7E2(Q%7E2R))%7E1(%7E3R%7E2S)%7E1(S%7E5%7E3T))%7E5(T%7E5P)) and it returned
that the expression is invalid.

```
Countermodel:
P:  false
Q:  true
R:  false
S:  false
T:  true
```

But the statement that I put into the TreeProofGenerator was not the original statement of the OP. One chnage was intorduced by a previous change of the post and one was introduced by me. The original statement of the OP is

$$((P \lor (Q \land R) ) \land (\lnot R \lor S) \land (S \to \lnot T)) \to ( T \to P)$$

For this staement the ProofTreeGenerator shows that the statement is valid by showing that the negation of the statement cannot be true.

[image]

Comment: I think you must have entered the connectives or nestings incorrectly.  (See my proof.)

Comment: @user3146 You are right, I made a type. Additionally the statement chnaged after you published your answer and before I worte my answer. I corrected the statement in the OP